# Is the following set a set of *increasing* absolutely continuous functions?

Tags: proof-writing, absolute-continuity

Is the following set a set of *increasing* absolutely continuous functions?

If $\mathcal{O}$ denote the collection of real-valued functions defined on $[0,1]$ that map every set of measure zero to a set of measure 0.

If so how to prove this?

Comment: Use asterisks for emphasis, not latex

Comment: Weird. Asterisks in the title don't get italicised

Comment: I do not know why this is correct?@jkabrg I believe that they get mapped to the same length which is zero

Comment: and how to prove this by the definition of absolutely continuous functions? and why they are increasing? @jkabrg

Comment: @jkabrg can I describe the set $\mathcal O$ by the following statement?  can I say that this statement $$m^*(f(E)) < \epsilon \quad \text{if} \quad m(E) < \delta $$